# KOMA-Script's scrreprt and appendix

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, appendices

For my thesis I am using the `scrreprt` document class for my document. The problem is that using this document class, you are forced to use chapters for each separate appendix (so appendix A, B et cetera). As my chapter headings take up much space (I like the twoline headings KOMA-Script offers, in which the first line is "Chapter 1." and the second is the title), I get lengthy appendices with relatively small type areas due to the large headings.

What I would like is to create smaller headings for my appendices whilst still maintaining the A, B, C et cetera numbering. One of two approaches would be nice:

1. Use `\section` in stead of `\chapter` for appendices. Thus using the smaller typeset section headings within my appendices. Currently I can't get this right, when I use sections my numbering switches from A, B, C etc to .1, .2, .3 which, clearly, is not what I want.
2. Manually adjusting the chapter heading for my appendices. KOMA-Script seems to have options for this (particularly `headings=onelineappendix`), but it set the headings for the entire document. I.e. changing this option means oneline headings for body chapter headings and appendices (which clearly is not what I want).

I hope anybody can help me achieve one of the two approaches.

Comment: `\clearpage\KOMAoption{headings}{small}\appendix` might just be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `headings=twolinechapter` with `headings=onelineappendix`

```
\documentclass[
    headings=twolinechapter, % or chapterprefix=true
    headings=onelineappendix % or appendixprefix=true
  ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

If the chapter headings in the appendix should have the same size as section headings you can use

```
\documentclass[
  headings=twolinechapter% or chapterprefix=true
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\appendix
\setkomafont{chapter}{\usekomafont{section}}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```